# File closes before async call finishes, causing IO error

Tags: python, asynchronous, io

I wrote a package that includes a function to upload something asynchronously. The intent is that the user can use my package, open a file, and upload it async. The problem is, depending on how the user writes their code, I get an IO error.

```
# EXAMPLE 1
with open("my_file", "rb") as my_file:
    package.upload(my_file)
# I/O operation on closed file error



#EXAMPLE 2
my_file = open("my_file", "rb")
package.upload(my_file)
# everything works
```

I understand that in the first example the file is closing immediately because the call is async. I don't know how to fix this though. I can't tell the user they can't open files in the style of example 1. Can I do something in my package.upload() implementation to prevent the file from closing?

Comment: you miss `with` ? i mean `with open ("my_file", "rb") as my_file:`

Comment: yeah sorry. Updated OP.

Comment: Your code takes responsibility for the file... that first usage is simply a bug. You need to document the API but other than that, if the caller closes the file, its on them.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov how is this unrelated to async programming? Here, a caller erroneously touches the file object after handing it off to another entity. The code would work well in a synchronous environment where all work by the called object is complete when the function returns. It is entirely related to async programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.dup` to duplicate the file descriptor and shield the async process from a close in the caller. The duplicated handle shares other characteristics of the original such as the current file position, so you are not completely shielded from bad things the caller can do.

This also limits your process to things that have file descriptors. If you stick to using the standard file calls, then a user can hand in any file-like object instead of just a file on disk.

```
def upload(my_file):
    my_file = os.fdopen(os.dup(my_file.fileno()))
    # ...queue for async
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `with` to open files, it will close when code block execution finishes inside `with`. In your case, just pass filename and `open` inside `asynchronus` function

Comment: This works but potentially reduces the usefulness of the API. One reason for letting the caller open the file is that the implementation can work with any file-like object, not just a file on disk. Suppose its a gzipped file or a file stream from a web request.